Group Redis "CLIENT LIST" by db on Heroku
I'm running Redis on Heroku. I'm trying to write a command that will run the CLIENT LIST command (https://redis.io/docs/latest/commands/client-list/) and then group the list by db. So ideally I'd end up with output like so:
DB 0: 10 connections
DB 1: 100 connections
DB 2: 1000 connections

How can I do this? Running on Heroku seems to make this even more challenging because I don't know if I have access to run redis-cli like I would in a typical Redis environment, see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/managing-heroku-redis-using-cli#redis-cli.
